# Unions and intersections of intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have got three tasks to do:

**Task#1**  Find $\bigcup_{n} [\frac{3}{n}, \frac{4}{n}]$

Let $A_n= [\frac{3}{n}, \frac{4}{n}]$ for $n=1,2,...$ then:

$A_1 = [3, 4]$

$A_2 = [\frac{3}{2}, 2]$

$A_3 = [1, \frac{4}{3}]$

$A_4 = [\frac{3}{4}, 1]$

And after I reach $n = min(3,4)$ (numerators): $A_i \subset [0,1]$  $\forall_{i > nin(3,4)}$. So it should mean that the union for $i > min(3,4) = [0,1]$ but to prove it, I need to show that there are no "gaps". I thought in this way: in that case $\forall_{n>min(3,4)} \frac{4}{n+1} > \frac{3}{n} $. And indeed, that happens. So I have no gaps "between" my subsets. So:

$\bigcup_{n} [\frac{3}{n}, \frac{4}{n}] = [0,\frac{3}{4}]\cup [\frac{3}{2}, 2]\cup  [3, 4].$ Is that right?

**Task#2** Find $\bigcap_n (\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{5}{n}+\frac{n}{10})$

Intersection, so I have to find $A_i: A_i\subseteq A_k \forall_{k\in N}$. And there comes the problem: 
$inf(\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{5}{n}+\frac{n}{10}) = \frac{99}{70}$ (it's local minima for $n = 7$) and $sup(\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{5}{n}+\frac{n}{10}) = 1$ but I strongly doubt if there exists a subset $(1,\frac{99}{70})$. Would an intersection be an... empty set?

**Task#3** Find $\bigcup_{r\in R}\{(x_1,x_2)\in R^2:(x_1-r)^2+(x_2+2r)^2 \leq r^2+1\}$

In this case  I have a series of circles, but I have no idea what curve limits these circles. If I had to guess I'd say a hyperbola, but I don't even know what to start with.

Comment: T1: the first set in your answer should be [0.4/3], not [0,3/4]. T2: why do you reject (1,99/70) as the intersection? T3. A hyperbola is a plausible guess. So what would the asymptotes be? It passes through the points $(\pm1,0)$.. Hence what would its equation be? Can you prove it?

Comment: T1: Agree, a mistake. Apart from that everything is alright?
T2: I'm not sure, I had a glimpse of a thought but now when I'm thinking about it the answer seems to be okay. Is it?
T3: Well, I don't really know. I mean, of course centers $S_i$ of these circles will be on a line $y=-2x$ and as $r \rightarrow \infty$ then $d(S,OX_1) \rightarrow r$ (so $x_1 = 0$ will be a right-side asymptote fo $x_2 <0$ and a left-side asymptote for $x_2>0$), but that's all I can figure out for now.

Comment: In T3 I tried to transform a circle **equation** to obtain an explicit formula for $y(x)$, and it gave me $y = - 2r \pm \sqrt{-x^2 +2xr+1}$. It turns out to be a parabolic-like function but the way it's placed in the coordinate system doesn't convince me at all. There will be intersections between this function for $r$ and a circle for $r+1$.

Comment: @almagest could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

For #1, use induction on $n\ge 3.$ For $n\ge 3$ let $S(n)$ be the statement $\cup_{j=3}^nA_j=[3/n, 4/3].$

Obviously $S(3)$ is true.

And we have $$S(n)\implies \cup_{j=3}^{n+1}A_j=[3/n, 4/3] \cup [3/(n+1),4/(n+1)]=$$ $$=[3/(n+1),4/3]\implies S(n+1)$$ because if $n\ge 3$ then $3/n\le 4/(n+1)<4/3$ and $3/(n+1)<3/n.$ (The main one being $3/n\le 4/(n+1)....$)

So $\cup_{n\ge 3}A_n=\cup_{n\ge 3}(\,\cup_{j=3}^nA_j\,)=\cup_{n\ge 3}[3/n,4/3]=(0,4/3].$

So $\cup_{n\ge 1}A_n=A_1\cup A_2\cup (0,4/3].$